# How to in aggregate distinct values in joined table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is  the schema:

```
post_tag = Table("post_tag", Base.metadata,
                 Column("post_id", Integer, ForeignKey("post.id")),
                 Column("tag_id ", Integer, ForeignKey("tag.id")))


class Post(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=post_tag, backref="post", cascade="all")
    collection_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("collection.id"))


class Tag(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column("description", UnicodeText, nullable=False, default="")
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("post.id"))


class Collection(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(128), nullable=False) 
    posts = relationship("Post", backref="collection", cascade="all,delete-orphan")

    tags = column_property(select([Tag])
                           .where(and_(Post.collection_id == id, Tag.post_id == Post.id))
                           .correlate_except(Tag))
```

Basically, `Post` to `Tag` is many-to-many and `Collection` to `Post` is one-to-many.

I want to `Collection.tags` return a distinct set of tags of posts in collection.

However, I get the following error when I access `Collection.tags`:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

**EDIT**

The SQL its generate

```
SELECT (SELECT tag.id, tag.description, tag.post_id 
FROM tag, post 
WHERE post.collection_id = collection.id AND tag.post_id = post.id) AS anon_1, collection.id AS collection_id, collection.title AS collection_title 
FROM collection 
WHERE collection.id = 1
```

I believe that `post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("post.id"))` is wrong as `post_id` is in post_tag. However, if I change  it to `post_tag.post_id`, it throws `AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'post_id'`

**EDIT2**

I change it to

```
tags = column_property(select([Tag])
                       .where(and_(Post.collection_id == id, post_tag.c.post_id == Post.id,
                                   post_tag.c.tag_id == Tag.id)))
```

While this works

```
SELECT tag.id, tag.description, tag.category_id, tag.post_id 
FROM tag, post, post_tag 
WHERE post.collection_id = 1 AND post_tag.post_id = post.id AND post_tag.tag_id = tag.id
```

but the query generate by SQLAlchemy does not

```
SELECT (SELECT tag.id, tag.description, tag.category_id, tag.post_id 
FROM tag, post, post_tag 
WHERE post.collection_id = collection.id AND post_tag.post_id = post.id AND post_tag.tag_id = tag.id) AS anon_1
FROM collection 
WHERE collection.id = 1
```

Comment: I think you need to show us the SQL (or the code that generates it) that gives the error. This usually means the query has `where mycol = (select ...)` and the `select` unexpectedly returns more than one row.

Comment: Probably the `Collection.tags` attribute used in an expression context. It should be a relationship attribute with a custom join instead.

Comment: @BoarGules I found the problem but I don't know how to solve it in SQLAlchemy. Can you take a look on my edits? I think the problem is I trying to use `column_property` to return a list instead of single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a [`column_property()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) you need a [`relationship()` with a composite "secondary"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins). A column property is handy for mapping some (scalar) SQL expression as a "column" that is loaded along other attributes. On the other hand you seem to want to map a collection of related `Tag` objects:

```
class Collection(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(128), nullable=False)
    posts = relationship("Post", backref="collection", cascade="all,delete-orphan")

    tags = relationship(
        "Tag", viewonly=True,
        primaryjoin="Collection.id == Post.collection_id",
        secondary="join(Post, post_tag)",
        secondaryjoin="Tag.id == post_tag.c.tag_id")
```

If you want to eager load the relationship, a bit like the column property would have, you could default to [`lazy="join"`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy). It's also possible to define the eager load strategy on a per query basis using [`Query.options()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.options):

```
session.query(Collection).\
    options(joinedload(Collection.tags)).\
    all()
```

Please note that your example has a typo(?) in the definition of the secondary table `post_tags`. The column `tag_id` has trailing whitespace in the name.

Comment: Thank you very much. The method I came up is only a function marked as `property` and query the result. Using `relationship` seems to be much better.